# Serializing a POJO based on a runtime whitelist of properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson2

Is it possible to serialize a whitelisted subset of a POJO's properties (where the whitelist is known only at runtime) using Jackson?

All the solutions I know of so far (Views, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` etc.) are static, compile-time solutions.

Further, my backend returns results in the following format:

```
{
    "outcome": "SUCCESS", // an enum
    "message": "Success.", // a message for the developer
    "result": {
        // Some result that's different for each call
    }
}
```

So I am looking for a solution that can be applied to only parts of the object graph (like the contents of the `result` property).

Comment: You could use a JSON filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at `@JsonFilter`.

See this tutorial on [serializing only fields that meet some criteria](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria) which includes details of this, and a couple of other methods.

For completeness

```
@JsonFilter("pojo-filter")
class Pojo {
    public int foo;
}

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
    .addFilter("pojo-filter", new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return "foo".equals(writer.getName()) 
                ? Random.nextBoolean()
                : true;
        }
    });

new ObjectMapper().writer().filters(filters).write(new Pojo());
```

Globally you can use [ObjectMapper.setFilterProvider](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setFilterProvider-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider-)

Comment: This means I have to obtain a writer from the `ObjectMapper` for every thread, add the `FilterProvider` and then serialize my object graph, correct?  Wouldn't this add runtime overhead?

Comment: You can use `ObjectMapper.setFilterProvider`

Comment: Using a filter works for me in may situations. Thanks.